# problem on probability calculation for sum of two probability distributions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expectation, variance

In a book I saw following problem. The answer at the back of the book is 0.75. But I am getting a different result. What am I doing wrong?

Problem: Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent Standard Uniform random variables. Find the probability of an event $\{0.5<(X+Y)<1.5 \}$.

My Solution:

Let $K=X+Y$.

$\text{E}(K)=0+0=0$.

$\text{Var}(K)=1+1=2$.

Let us standardize bounds:

$z_1 = (0.5-0)/\sqrt{2}=0.3536$.

$z_2=(1.5-0)/\sqrt{2}=1.0607$.

Then:

$P\{0.5<K<1.5\}=P\{0.3536<Z<1.0607\}=\Phi(1.0607)-\Phi(0.3536)=0.8584-0.6368=0.2216$

The $\Phi$ values are taken from a table in the back of the book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables are *uniform*, not *normal*. You want the area in the unit square between the lines $x+y=0.5$ and $x+y=1.5$. That strip is all of the square except two right triangles of side $\frac12$, so its area is

$$1-2\cdot\frac18=\frac34\;.$$

Comment: Oww. Misread that. Thanks.

Comment: @anapprentice: You’re welcome.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I am not the original poster but is there another way to set this up without needing to notice a "square"? is this the same as asking for probability of $.5 < X+Y < 1.5$ when $X$ and $Y$ each can take on uniformly any value between $0$ and $1$? Is there a way to do this with calculus?

Comment: @user51819: The integral that you’d use would just be calculating the area of that strip.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott What I mean is that I don't know how to set up the integral. I tried doing $\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} (x+y)~dx~dy$ but then this says nothing about the bounds in question and figure I'm accidentally computing the expected value of $x+y$ rather than probability.

Comment: @user51819: You want the integral of $1$ over the part of the square in which $0.5<x+y<1.5$. That’s $$\int_0^{0.5}\int_{0.5-x}^1dydx+\int_{0.5}^1\int_0^{1.5-x}dydx\;,$$ which is just a fancy way of calculating the area of the strip.

Comment: If I have $0 \leq x \leq 1$ then $0.5 < x+y < 1.5$ becomes $0.5-x < y < 1.5-x$, but then account for $y$'s bounds via $\max(0.5-x, 0) < y < \min(1.5-x, 1)$ And $0.5-x >= 0$ when $x<=.5$, and if this is true the upper bound is $1$, so $\int_{0}^{.5} \int_{0.5-x}^{1} dydx$ and the other side is therefore $\int_{.5}^{1} \int_{0}^{1.5-x} dydx$, which seems to match!

Comment: (sorry it helps me to derive the result myself as well, to make sure I understand). Thanks!

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Can you explain how you set up those integrals, especially bounds?

Comment: @user51819:  thank you for your explanation. I understand why the bounds are set up like that. I still do not understand why there is only "1" in the integrals, when we need "x+y".

Comment: @anapprentice When you are given a probability density function, the probability (between two cutoffs) is equal to the area under the curve. A standard uniform variable has $0 < x < 1$ and therefore height $\frac{1}{1-0} = 1$. So the "height" of the function is always $1$. What differs is what cutoffs we look at.